# SQL query returns void in Spring Boot application but does not in H2

Tags: sql, spring-boot

Good evening,

I'm sure I'm missing something about how to write queries in a Spring Boot application and would appreciate correction.

SQL query in h2-console:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE first_name = 'morton';
```

returns '1'

in Spring application:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT 'customer_id' FROM customers WHERE 'first_name' = ?1")
public Long findIdByName(String name);
```

returns null

Error text:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT 'customer_id' FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE 'first_name' = %[*]?"; expected "ALL, ANY, SOME"; SQL statement:
SELECT 'customer_id' FROM customers WHERE 'first_name' = %? [42001-200]
```

What is wrong with the second query?

Let me know if you need the full stack trace.

Thanks

Comment: Have to remove single quote from query. For this kind of problem you're tested using manually fire query on dml script page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove single inverted commas from the query.

Change

```
SELECT 'customer_id' FROM customers WHERE 'first_name' = ?1
```

To

```
SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE first_name = ?1
```